# Блокировка пользователя

Tags: javascript, php

Блокирую я пользователя по IP, он его меняет и блокировки нет. Блокирую я его по ключу, который записан в cookie или в localStorage, он его чистит и блокировки нет. Так как я устал бороться со спамерами на своём сайте, которые обходят блокировку, как  нефиг делать, то хотелось бы спросить у Вас - как заблокировать пользователя так, чтоб даже через другой браузер он не смог войти на мой сайт и выдавалось сообщение об блокировке? Есть ли способы борьбы?

Comment: заставить зарегистрироваться пользователей, если они хотят оставить комментарий или ещё что-то. И блокировать пользователей. Первые комментарии\сообщения от пользователей не публиковать сразу, а пропускать через модераторов.

Comment: Ни у php, ни у JS, нет прав на выполнение вашей задачи. Вы не сможете никак заблокировать пользователя, он может сменить IP, очистить COOKIE, сменить браузер и ничего по-сути не выйдет. Есть одно небольшое решение, связанное на FINGERPRINT, сам с этим не сталкивался, но как вариант может быть. В вашем же случае, ваших спамеров необходимо заставлять проходить авторизацию/регистрацию с капчей, а их спам - модерировать, как и написали уже выше. Есть разъяснение на английском по FingerPrint на Canvas - https://hovav.net/ucsd/dist/canvas.pdf

Comment: Вы никак не определите, зашёл ли с другого браузера другой человек или тот же самый. Поэтому только вышеупомянутая авторизация/регистрация с капчей.

Comment: @andreymal , что вы скажете по этому поводу: https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2 ?

Comment: @MoloF что если вместо андроида я возьму айфон и вместо хрома сафари, то этот ваш fingerprintjs2 нифига меня не опознает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут нужен комплексный подход:

1. Определение бота путем рендера js'ом поля комментария например, либо любого другого поля формы.
2. Смотреть по юзер агенту если агент не браузер и не поисковый бот то блок.
3. Авторизация и регистрация либо аутентификация.
4. Премодераци и постмодерация

Так же можно легко определить бота, если сделать скрытую ссылку на специальную форму добавления чего либо. И если она была отправлена то блокировать ip, так как пользователь не увидел бы этой ссылки.

Так же косвенно можно определить:

1. User-agent браузер, версию и ос
2. Локализацию пользователя (по гео-данным)
3. В локал сторедж и куки можно записать некий ключ.

По совокупности этих признаков можно примерно определить тот же пользователь это или нет. Я бы сделал, некую процентную гродацию что то вроде (u-a+geo+local_storage)(old)/(u-a+geo+local_storage)(new)*100 = неблагонадежность. так вы можете получить процент на сколько ранее заблокированный пользователь совпадает с вновь вошедшем, а если еще учесть патерны поведения, клики по ссылкам, ввод комментария через какое либо времени и добавлять эти доли к рейтингу благонадежности, то можно будет с увереностью сказать что пользователь именно тот который был ранее на сайте. При достижения 95% неблагонадежности.

p.s. Понятно что алгоритм не из легких но надеюсь кому нибудь понадобиться.

Comment: у меня чат сделан на websocket, так что, думаю, этот алгоритм попробовать. Спасибо!

Comment: Тогда уж можно использовать ReCaptchaV3 для таких целей, который на всех страницах будет сидеть, чтобы не создавать свой велосипед неблагонадёжности.

Comment: @MoloF дельное замечание но алгоритм имеет место быть